# Quickbooks Desktop: Billable status is not applicable for the specified Account type

Tags: java, php, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I have attempted to submit the following request content to Quickbooks Desktop by using v3 QB REST API

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:Purchase xmlns:ns0="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" domain="QB">
  <ns0:TxnDate>2014-03-10</ns0:TxnDate>
  <ns0:PrivateNote>Report to QBD</ns0:PrivateNote>
    <ns0:Line>
    <ns0:Description>60000 Advertising and Promotion</ns0:Description>
    <ns0:Amount>10.00</ns0:Amount>
    <ns0:DetailType>AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail</ns0:DetailType>
    <ns0:AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail>
      <ns0:CustomerRef name="TOEIC">QB:17</ns0:CustomerRef>
      <ns0:AccountRef name="Advertising and Promotion">QB:7</ns0:AccountRef>
      <ns0:BillableStatus>NotBillable</ns0:BillableStatus>
      <ns0:TaxCodeRef>NON</ns0:TaxCodeRef>
    </ns0:AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail>
  </ns0:Line>
  <ns0:Line>
    <ns0:Description>12100 Inventory Asset</ns0:Description>
    <ns0:Amount>4.00</ns0:Amount>
    <ns0:DetailType>AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail</ns0:DetailType>
    <ns0:AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail>
      <ns0:CustomerRef name="Future Press">QB:14</ns0:CustomerRef>
      <ns0:AccountRef name="Inventory Asset">QB:31</ns0:AccountRef>
      <ns0:BillableStatus>NotBillable</ns0:BillableStatus>
      <ns0:TaxCodeRef>NON</ns0:TaxCodeRef>
    </ns0:AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail>
  </ns0:Line>
  <ns0:Line>
    <ns0:Description>50000 Cost of Goods Sold</ns0:Description>
    <ns0:Amount>5.00</ns0:Amount>
    <ns0:DetailType>AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail</ns0:DetailType>
    <ns0:AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail>
      <ns0:CustomerRef name="Pawn Shop Chronicles">QB:19</ns0:CustomerRef>
      <ns0:AccountRef name="Automobile Expense">QB:8</ns0:AccountRef>
      <ns0:BillableStatus>NotBillable</ns0:BillableStatus>
      <ns0:TaxCodeRef>NON</ns0:TaxCodeRef>
    </ns0:AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail>
  </ns0:Line>
  <ns0:AccountRef name="My Bank Account">QB:30</ns0:AccountRef>
  <ns0:PaymentType>Check</ns0:PaymentType>
  <ns0:EntityRef name="ExpenseCloud">QB:5</ns0:EntityRef>
  <ns0:TotalAmt>19.00</ns0:TotalAmt>
</ns0:Purchase>
```

There is an item with **Account=Inventory Asset**(Account Type is Other Current Asset) which is marked as NotBillable. Since i can submit this request content using Java API v2 to Quickbooks Desktop and it works well. But now, i always get this error **Operation failed with errors: Billable status is not applicable for the specified Account type.**

However, i can duplicate directly that transaction in Quickbooks Desktop Application without error. I'm trying to solve it but nothing help so i guess this is a problem of QB API.

Please advice.
Thanks

Comment: If you can create this entry from QBD UI, then please query that object using V3 QBD. That way, you can verify the response. I'll try to reproduce this use case using V3 and confirm the behaviour. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the docs here-
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/95_legacy/qbd_v3/qbd_v3_reference/030_entity_services_reference/purchase
Billable status is applicable only when there is CustomerRef passed in the request and applicable to the specific account types: 1. Expense 2. Other Expense 3. Cost of Goods Sold

Please check if your Account types match the above.

Comment: Well, i did not think Intuit has prevented AccountType=Other Current Asset since it's still working in Java API v2. But it's indeed.